Clangd in QtCreator
I am trying to configure clangd at work. Currently it shows me warnings which suggests it is trying to be c++98 compatible. Some of the warnings I see is 'nullptr' is incompatible with C++98 and 'override' keyword is incompatible with C++98. We use CMake to configure our build system where we set the c++ version to 17 with set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17). I am now trying to configure clangd through editing C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\clangd\config.yaml where I am following the clangd documentation. Currently my config.yaml looks like this:
CompileFlags:
  Add: [-std=c++17]

I have found this answer which suggests doing the same as I am doing now.
Edit:
Things got much better by adding -Wno-c++98-compat
CompileFlags:
  Add: [-std=c++17, -Wno-c++98-compat]

I am still seeing c++17 related warnings such as Nested namespace definition is a C++17 extension; define each namespace separately (fix available). Is there a better way to configure this than adding a bunch of -Wno rules?

You shouldn't be getting the "Nested namespace definition is a C++17 extension" diagnostic if you're using -std=c++17, so something is going wrong. Please attach clangd logs for further diagnosis.
